# Question about Sequelize database migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, continuous-integration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I’m using Sequelize as an ORM for a Postgres database. I started learning & using Sequelize migrations and seeding features. So for I understood that the primary purpose of migrations is to reliably make changes to the database schema without affecting the data inside. I created the first migration to create tables based on the current schemas. I also created the first seed to populate the tables with some data. Now I want to understand:
How do I apply this migration (and future ones)  to spin up a database in production (the first time) and in development? 
Ideally, since these migrations keep track of the schema changes, I can just run them in any environment (production, staging, development) and it will create/update the tables in that environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough overview of how migration works.

If you did a migration(`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`), then your table must have a table named `SequelizeMeta` or something similar to that under the database.

```
// SequelizeMeta
name
xxxx-create-user-table
xxxx-update-user-table
...
```

You can check which migrations are applied or not by matching the names there.

So it's a git for a database schema.

Now let's answer the questions.

Q: How do I apply this migration (and future ones) to spin up a database in production (the first time) and in development?

A: access your server instance (it can be ec2 or your local machine) and run migration there (`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`).

Typically you'll use different databases for different environments, for example, use local MySQL database for development and use `AWS RDS` for production, etc.

So you should do migration after deployment if you have new undone migrations. (access server instance and run migration)